# Proving the Equivalence of REGEX r^n and r^{..n} when r Is Nullable

Tags: fl.formal-languages, proofs, regular-expressions, set-theory

Im seeking clarification and a rigorous proof regarding the equivalence of **r^n** and **r^{..n}** in the context of formal languages, particularly when **r** is **nullable**.

To clarify the terminology:

- **r** denotes the regular expression
- **r^n** denotes exactly n repetitions of **r**.
- **r^{..n}** represents any number of repetitions of **r**, from zero to n.

I've come across a statement suggesting that when r is nullable (able to produce an empty string), **r^n** is equivalent (equals) to **r^{..n}**.

This concept makes sense to me intuitively, but I'm looking for a more formal proof or example to solidify my understanding.

Could someone provide a clear and formal proof, or perhaps an illustrative example, that demonstrates why **r^n** is indeed equivalent to **r^{..n}** when r is nullable?

I appreciate any insights and guidance on this matter.

Comment: This is not a research-level question, but a rather trivial consequence of the definition. You should take the question to https://cs.stackexchange.com , not here.